# How to inject HttpContextAccessor directly from ConfigureServices method

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

My goal is to set a username string based on the environment I'll be working on that must be:

- an arbitrary string for the development and staging environment
- the `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` in production.

This is because I have to be able to simulate different kind of users and I achieve this by calling the `FindByIdAsync` method on my custom implementation of `UserIdentity` using this username string as a parameter, like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    UserManager<AppUser> userManager;
    AppUser connectedUser;

    public HomeController(UserManager<AppUser> usrMgr, IContextUser ctxUser)
    {
        connectedUser = usrMgr.FindByNameAsync(ctxUser.ContextUserId).Result;
    }
}
```

I started creating three `appsettings.{environment}.json` file for the three usual development, staging and production environments; development and staging .json files both have this configuration:

```
...
"Data": {
  ...
  "ConnectedUser" : "__ADMIN"
}
...
```

while the production environment configuration file *doesn't* have this key.

I have created a simple interface

```
public interface IContextUser
{
    public string ContextUserId { get; }
}
```

and its implementation:

```
public class ContextUser : IContextUser
{
    string contextUser;
    IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor;

    public ContextUser(IHttpContextAccessor ctxAccessor, string ctxUser = null)
    {
        contextUser = ctxUser;
        contextAccessor = ctxAccessor;
    }

    public string ContextUserId => contextUser ?? contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
}
```

Now, I thought of simply configuring the `ConfigureServices` method in the `Startup` class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // --- add other services --- //

    string ctxUser = Configuration["Data:ConnectedUser"];
    services.AddSingleton(service => new ContextUser( ??? , ctxUser ));

}
```

but it needs an `IHttpContextAccessor` object, that seems unavailable at this stage of the application. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `HttpContextAccessor` makes use of a static `AsyncLocal<T>` property under the covers, which means that any `HttpContextAccessor` implementation will access the same data. This means you can simply do the following:

```cs
services.AddSingleton(c => new ContextUser(new HttpContextAccessor(), ctxUser));

// Don't forget to call this; otherwise the HttpContext property will be
// null on production.
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

If you find this too implicit, or don't the `HttpContextAccessor` implementation from breaking in the future, you can also do the following:

```cs
var accessor = new HttpContextAccessor();

services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor>(accessor);
services.AddSingleton(c => new ContextUser(accessor, ctxUser));
```

Or you can "pull out" the registered instance out of the `ServiceCollection` class:

```cs
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

var accessor = (IHttpContextAccessor)services.Last(
    s => s.ServiceType == typeof(IHttpContextAccessor)).ImplementationInstance;

services.AddSingleton(c => new ContextUser(accessor, ctxUser));
```

What I find a more pleasant solution, however, especially from a design perspective, is to split the `ContextUser` class; it currently seems to implement two different solutions. You can split those:

```cs
public sealed class HttpContextContextUser : IContextUser
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor accessor;

    public HttpContextContextUser(IHttpContextAccessor accessor) =>
        this.accessor = accessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("accessor");

    public string ContextUserId => this.accessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
}


public sealed class FixedContextUser : IContextUser
{
    public FixedContextUser(string userId) =>
        this.ContextUserId = userId ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("userId");

    public string ContextUserId { get; }
}
```

Now, depending on the environment you're running in, you register either one of them:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

    if (this.Configuration.IsProduction())
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IContextUser, HttpContextContextUser>();
    }
    else
    {
        string ctxUser = Configuration["Data:ConnectedUser"];
        services.AddSingleton<IContextUser>(new FixedContextUser(ctxUser));
    }
}
```

Comment: I like very much your alternate solution of splitting the ContextUser class, and that's what I did. Thanks.